# How to blink LED after every 1 second using timers in LPC 1768 (C Programming)?

Tags: c, lpc, nxp-microcontroller

I am new in micro controller programming .I am using embedded C platform for coding. I want to blink LED after every 1 second using timers in LPC 1768. I have option of generating delay using empty "for" loops and crystal frequency for calculation of counter value. But this delay is not precise.

In the given board LPC 1768 is connected to the LEDs through [PCA 9532](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwic9uuNhIzQAhWJq48KHY8OAPoQFggkMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata_sheet%2FPCA9532.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEP7FGN_UaJvkOlytWlHPVVx6p5EQ) I2c bus. For controlling LEDs I should use SDA and SCL pins of PCA 9532 .I want to make use of LPC 1768 timers for generating delay of 1 second so that I could blink the LED with 1 second time interval.But problem is that **LPC1768 is not directly connected to LED . PCA 9532 is in between them**. So can anybody tell me how can I perform it?

Comment: Just use the PWM peripherial...

Comment: Take a look to that blog [Timer Interrupt in LPC1768 Microcontroller](http://binaryupdates.com/timer-interrupt-in-lpc1768-microcontroller/).

Comment: Did you bother to read UM10360 at all?

Comment: Read [this](https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/LPC1768:_Timers).

Comment: @TurboJ but LPC1768 is not directly connected to LED .  PCA 9532 is in between them . So what should be done ?

Comment: That PCA9532 chip has its own timing source and has even an example with 1 Hz in the linked datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to talk to the [PCA9532](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9532.pdf?) via I2C.

- configure the LPC pins to use I2C
- write a simple driver which writes commands over I2C.
- configure the PCA9532 via these commands.

PS: If you don't want to write real I2C drivers, you could bit-bang the commands. Be sure to reconfigure the GPIO (SDA) as input to read ACK from chip.

PPS: you find the command structure in the linked datasheet in chapter 7.1 and a sample communication in chapter 8.2.

Hope that's a first help.